# Returning parent json key after filtering for a specific key:value pair

Tags: python, json

I am call some API that returns a large API block.  I need some help figuring out the most efficient way of filtering json.  I've only ever interacted with specific sets or fields but not identifying a single key:value pair and then finding the parent.  Once I find the parent, i want to only return the parent block.  How would I go about doing it?  I'm also trying to understand what kind of logic to use here.

Sample Block below.  I would want to find 'itemtype:19' and then return '86' and then once I have '86' i can grab the values i need from 86.  Example [86][itemDefinition][name].

```
       },
        "86":{
           "saleStatus":8,
           "failureIndexes":[
              3
           ],
           "augments":0,
           "vendorItemIndex":86,
           "itemHash":1476367343,
           "quantity":1,
           "costs":[
              {
                 "itemHash":4046539562,
                 "quantity":10
              }
           ],
           "itemDefinition":{
              "displayProperties":{
                 "description":"",
                 "name":"Sword Ammo Finder",
                 "icon":"/common/destiny2_content/icons/793bc0219a88f4454e413217628c40f0.png",
                 "iconSequences":[
                    {
                       "frames":[
                          "/common/destiny2_content/icons/793bc0219a88f4454e413217628c40f0.png"
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "frames":[
                          "/common/destiny2_content/icons/e0d0166080ae8c0630338738ac6cff04.png"
                       ]
                    }
                 ],
                 "hasIcon":True
              },
              "tooltipNotifications":[
                 
              ],
              "collectibleHash":1263137395,
              "backgroundColor":{
                 "colorHash":0,
                 "red":0,
                 "green":0,
                 "blue":0,
                 "alpha":0
              },
              "itemTypeDisplayName":"Helmet Armor Mod",
              "uiItemDisplayStyle":"ui_display_style_energy_mod",
              "itemTypeAndTierDisplayName":"Common Helmet Armor Mod",
              "displaySource":"",
              "tooltipStyle":"build",
              "action":{
                 "verbName":"Dismantle",
                 "verbDescription":"",
                 "isPositive":False,
                 "requiredCooldownSeconds":0,
                 "requiredItems":[
                    
                 ],
                 "progressionRewards":[
                    
                 ],
                 "actionTypeLabel":"shard",
                 "rewardSheetHash":0,
                 "rewardItemHash":0,
                 "rewardSiteHash":0,
                 "requiredCooldownHash":0,
                 "deleteOnAction":True,
                 "consumeEntireStack":False,
                 "useOnAcquire":False
              },
              "inventory":{
                 "maxStackSize":1,
                 "bucketTypeHash":2422292810,
                 "recoveryBucketTypeHash":0,
                 "tierTypeHash":3340296461,
                 "isInstanceItem":False,
                 "nonTransferrableOriginal":False,
                 "tierTypeName":"Common",
                 "tierType":2,
                 "expirationTooltip":"",
                 "expiredInActivityMessage":"",
                 "expiredInOrbitMessage":"",
                 "suppressExpirationWhenObjectivesComplete":True
              },
              "plug":{
                 "insertionRules":[
                    
                 ],
                 "plugCategoryIdentifier":"enhancements.v2_head",
                 "plugCategoryHash":2912171003,
                 "onActionRecreateSelf":False,
                 "actionRewardSiteHash":0,
                 "actionRewardItemOverrideHash":0,
                 "insertionMaterialRequirementHash":1564811296,
                 "previewItemOverrideHash":0,
                 "enabledMaterialRequirementHash":0,
                 "enabledRules":[
                    
                 ],
                 "uiPlugLabel":"",
                 "plugStyle":0,
                 "plugAvailability":0,
                 "alternateUiPlugLabel":"",
                 "alternatePlugStyle":0,
                 "isDummyPlug":False,
                 "energyCost":{
                    "energyCost":2,
                    "energyTypeHash":728351493,
                    "energyType":1
                 }
              },
              "acquireRewardSiteHash":0,
              "acquireUnlockHash":0,
              "investmentStats":[
                 {
                    "statTypeHash":3779394102,
                    "value":2,
                    "isConditionallyActive":False
                 }
              ],
              "perks":[
                 {
                    "requirementDisplayString":"",
                    "perkHash":3553498179,
                    "perkVisibility":0
                 }
              ],
              "allowActions":True,
              "doesPostmasterPullHaveSideEffects":False,
              "nonTransferrable":True,
              "itemCategoryHashes":[
                 59,
                 4104513227,
                 1362265421
              ],
              "specialItemType":0,
              "itemType":19,
              "itemSubType":0,
              "classType":3,
              "breakerType":0,
              "equippable":False,
              "defaultDamageType":0,
              "isWrapper":False,
              "hash":1476367343,
              "index":8169,
              "redacted":False,
              "blacklisted":False
           }
        },
        "170":{
           "saleStatus":1,
           "failureIndexes":[
              
           ],
           "augments":0,
           "vendorItemIndex":170,
           "itemHash":2979281381,
           "quantity":1,
           "costs":[
              {
                 "itemHash":3853748946,
                 "quantity":1
              },
              {
                 "itemHash":1022552290,
                 "quantity":10
              },
              {
                 "itemHash":2014411539,
                 "quantity":25
              },
              {
                 "itemHash":3159615086,
                 "quantity":5000
              }
           ],
           "overrideNextRefreshDate":"2020-09-28T17:00:00Z",
           "itemDefinition":{
              "displayProperties":{
                 "description":"A collection of universal components that can be used to infuse power between gear items. Can be purchased from the Gunsmith or acquired from special reward sources.",
                 "name":"Upgrade Module",
                 "icon":"/common/destiny2_content/icons/62b016b25d8589f2b15c38890d2b24c3.jpg",
                 "hasIcon":True
              },
              "tooltipNotifications":[
                 
              ],
              "backgroundColor":{
                 "colorHash":0,
                 "red":94,
                 "green":12,
                 "blue":142,
                 "alpha":255
              },
              "itemTypeDisplayName":"Material",
              "uiItemDisplayStyle":"",
              "itemTypeAndTierDisplayName":"Legendary Material",
              "displaySource":"",
              "action":{
                 "verbName":"Discard",
                 "verbDescription":"",
                 "isPositive":False,
                 "requiredCooldownSeconds":0,
                 "requiredItems":[
                    
                 ],
                 "progressionRewards":[
                    
                 ],
                 "rewardSheetHash":0,
                 "rewardItemHash":0,
                 "rewardSiteHash":0,
                 "requiredCooldownHash":0,
                 "deleteOnAction":True,
                 "consumeEntireStack":False,
                 "useOnAcquire":False
              },
              "inventory":{
                 "stackUniqueLabel":"v460.materials.currencies.infusion_token",
                 "maxStackSize":25,
                 "bucketTypeHash":1469714392,
                 "recoveryBucketTypeHash":215593132,
                 "tierTypeHash":4008398120,
                 "isInstanceItem":False,
                 "nonTransferrableOriginal":False,
                 "tierTypeName":"Legendary",
                 "tierType":5,
                 "expirationTooltip":"",
                 "expiredInActivityMessage":"",
                 "expiredInOrbitMessage":"",
                 "suppressExpirationWhenObjectivesComplete":True
              },
              "acquireRewardSiteHash":0,
              "acquireUnlockHash":0,
              "investmentStats":[
                 
              ],
              "perks":[
                 
              ],
              "allowActions":True,
              "doesPostmasterPullHaveSideEffects":False,
              "nonTransferrable":True,
              "itemCategoryHashes":[
                 40,
                 52
              ],
              "specialItemType":0,
              "itemType":0,
              "itemSubType":0,
              "classType":3,
              "breakerType":0,
              "equippable":False,
              "defaultDamageType":0,
              "isWrapper":False,
              "hash":2979281381,
              "index":10741,
              "redacted":False,
              "blacklisted":False
           }
        },
```

Comment: Do you mean to parse the json manually and skipping anything you're not looking for, or to traverse the big dictionary fast?

Comment: Traverse it quickly, find 'itemType:19' and then go back and find the parent which can be used to pull any data in the parent stanza.